# Multiplexing 24V signals to DC load generator

Tags: powermosfet, electronic-load

(Electronics beginner)

I have a DC load generator ([TENMA 72-13210](https://se.farnell.com/tenma/72-13210/elektron-dc-last-prog-30a-120v/dp/2848407) a rebrand of Korad KEL103).
[image]

I want to use if for testing a custom board designed in-house with 30 outputs each capable of driving **10A** loads at **24V**. The output signal is either **0V/24V** or a **PWM** signal. The board measures the current produced on each output. I want to verify how well the boards measurements matches the actual load reported from the load generator.

My DC load **only supports one input** so I can only test one output at a time. It would be great if I could create a gadget that let me remotely switch between which output is connected to the DC load. Something that I can control from my PC via some means.

I view it as a spare-time learning project (but that will be useful for me in my work now that I'm forced to work from home during the pandemic). Ideally I would want the ability to test several outputs at once, but I want to make the gadget simple enough so that I will be able to finish it. By **reusing the DC load** I get rid of the complexity from implementing my own DC load.

I guess I'm thinking of something similar to a [Multiplexer Switch](https://www.keysight.com/en/pc-1000003025%3Aepsg%3Apgr/multiplexer-modules-for-34980a?cc=SE&lc=eng) but much simpler and cheaper - a weekend project.

[image]

How can I do "time-divided multiplexing" of the output signal to the board? Do I need to create a tree of power transistors that I control from a microcontroller or SBC (raspberrypi/beaglebone black/...) or are there ready made components to achieve what I want?

- Do I need to worry about one output back-powering another? If so, how prevent it? Diodes? Is [break-before-make](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/liner_load-switch-ics/load-switch-ics11.html) the term used here?
- What are the trade-offs between using relays; discrete MOSFETs; or integrated Load Switches?
- How much will the switching mechanism affect the readings? How much load will they add?

Sorry for the vague question. I'll try to fill in details as I learn about the proper terms.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I updated the description but it's very vague. A board made at my company and I'm afraid of saying too much if I started describing it. As a spare-time project I thought it would be enlighting to try and design a multiplexer.

Comment: All of this depends on the nature of the signals and the current. Are they just plain 24VDC on/off or something analog?

Comment: It seems likely that you need to be testing more than one output at a time.  Can your load bank do that?

Comment: If the outputs are intended to be used at the same time, then that is how you should test.

Comment: @KH I've updated the text with info about the nature of the signals and why I at this point is restricting myself to just testing one output at a time (the DC load only has one input and I don't want to take on the complexity of implementing my own DC load at this point - though it would be an interesting project later on).

Comment: @Lundin I've updated the text with info about the nature of the signals.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I want to be able to graph the DUTs self-reported current/voltage values against the programmable Loads current/voltage for a set of measurement points 0.1A, 0.2A, ...1A, 1.1A, ...10A. I can control the load and the DUT from my PC. I would like to also be able to control an multiplex in-between for convinient switching between outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are simple ways like a relay board, but if you want to use mosfets here is one option.

You can just get two of [these](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9056)(Any multiplexer will do as long as there are 30 total outputs.), 30 p-mosfets capable of 10A, 30 level shifters, and a raspberry pi/arduino/beaglebone.

You can make this cheaper, but more time consuming if you only do half of the outputs at a time.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRfl7K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOTES:

There are many factors that go into choosing a mosfet. VGS and RDSOn are the most important in your case because we are dealing with a DC high current signal.

EDIT: Also Vgs is important in your case because you have a 24 V signal most mosfets are only 20V rated. I have updated the schematic to include a voltage divider for the gate.

There are multiplexers that work with communication protocols like I2C and that is another option if you are running low on outputs.

Comment: Note: the load is 2.4 ohms.  Also - if the load can tolerate having its ground switched, you can eliminate the level shift transistor from each output.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a bank of 30 power MOSFETs on a heatsink, back in the day you could do this with three TTL chips connected to a parallel printer port.  Today I'm told that the latest versions of Windows don't allow direct hardware register access, but I have not tried this myself.  There are many small uC boards that can act as an I/O interface between a serial or USB port and a bunch of parallel outputs to drive the FETs. For example, a small Arduino with an I/O or output-only shield could do this easily if you already have programming experience.